# Binary Tree implementation using a recursive approach

Tags: java, recursion, tree, project

Project: "Create an implementation of a binary tree using the recursive approach introduced in the chapter. In this approach, each node is a binary tree. Thus a binary tree contains a reference to the element stored at its root as well as references to its left and right subtrees. You may also want to include a reference to its parent."

Question: 
In the chapter they give a binary tree implementation (code shown below) and I'm not sure what this project wants me to do differently then the implementation in the book.
All I can see is to fill in a few missing details like a few methods and also adding a parent reference. I know as a final project though this isn't what it's asking.

```
Binary Tree Class:
`
//*******************************************************************
// BinaryTree.java Java Foundations
//
// Defines the interface to a binary tree collection.
//*******************************************************************
package javafoundations;
import java.util.Iterator;
public interface BinaryTree<T> extends Iterable<T>
{
    // Returns the element stored in the root of the tree.
    public T getRootElement();
    // Returns the left subtree of the root.
    public BinaryTree<T> getLeft();
    // Returns the right subtree of the root.
    public BinaryTree<T> getRight();
    // Returns true if the binary tree contains an element that
    // matches the specified element and false otherwise.
    public boolean contains (T target);
    // Returns a reference to the element in the tree matching
    // the specified target.
    public T find (T target);
    // Returns true if the binary tree contains no elements, and
    // false otherwise.
    public boolean isEmpty();
    // Returns the number of elements in this binary tree.
    public int size();
    // Returns the string representation of the binary tree.
    public String toString();
    // Returns a preorder traversal on the binary tree.
    public Iterator<T> preorder();
    // Returns an inorder traversal on the binary tree.
    public Iterator<T> inorder();
    // Returns a postorder traversal on the binary tree.
    public Iterator<T> postorder();
    // Performs a level-order traversal on the binary tree.
    public Iterator<T> levelorder(); 
}
```

`

```
LinkedBinaryTree class:
`
//*******************************************************************
// LinkedBinaryTree.java Java Foundations
//
// Implements a binary tree using a linked representation.
//*******************************************************************
package javafoundations;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javafoundations.*;
import javafoundations.exceptions.*;
public class LinkedBinaryTree<T> implements BinaryTree<T>
{
    protected BTNode<T> root;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates an empty binary tree.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public LinkedBinaryTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates a binary tree with the specified element as its root.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public LinkedBinaryTree (T element)
    {
        root = new BTNode<T>(element);
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates a binary tree with the two specified subtrees.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public LinkedBinaryTree (T element, LinkedBinaryTree<T> left,
    LinkedBinaryTree<T> right)
    {
        root = new BTNode<T>(element);
        root.setLeft(left.root);
        root.setRight(right.root);
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the element stored in the root of the tree. Throws an
    // EmptyCollectionException if the tree is empty.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public T getRootElement()
    {
        if (root == null)
            throw new EmptyCollectionException 
            ("Get root operation " + "failed. The tree is empty.");
        return root.getElement();
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the left subtree of the root of this tree.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public LinkedBinaryTree<T> getLeft()
    {
        if (root == null)
            throw new EmptyCollectionException 
                      ("Get left operation " + "failed. The tree is empty.");
        LinkedBinaryTree<T> result = new LinkedBinaryTree<T>();
        result.root = root.getLeft();
        return result;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the element in this binary tree that matches the
    // specified target. Throws a ElementNotFoundException if the
    // target is not found.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public T find (T target)
    {
        BTNode<T> node = null;
        if (root != null)
            node = root.find(target);
        if (node == null)
            throw new ElementNotFoundException
               ("Find operation failed. " + "No such element in tree.");
        return node.getElement();
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the number of elements in this binary tree.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public int size()
    {
        int result = 0;
        if (root != null)
            result = root.count();
        return result;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Populates and returns an iterator containing the elements in
    // this binary tree using an inorder traversal.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public Iterator<T> inorder()
    {
        ArrayIterator<T> iter = new ArrayIterator<T>();
        if (root != null)
            root.inorder (iter);
        return iter;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Populates and returns an iterator containing the elements in
    // this binary tree using a levelorder traversal.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public Iterator<T> levelorder()
    {
        LinkedQueue<BTNode<T>> queue = new LinkedQueue<BTNode<T>>();
        ArrayIterator<T> iter = new ArrayIterator<T>();
        if (root != null)
        {
            queue.enqueue(root);
            while (!queue.isEmpty())
            {
                BTNode<T> current = queue.dequeue();
                iter.add (current.getElement());
                if (current.getLeft() != null)
                    queue.enqueue(current.getLeft());
                if (current.getRight() != null)
                    queue.enqueue(current.getRight());
            }
        }
        return iter;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Satisfies the Iterable interface using an inorder traversal.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return inorder();
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // The following methods are left as programming projects.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // public LinkedBinaryTree<T> getRight() { }
    // public boolean contains (T target) { }
    // public boolean isEmpty() { }
    // public String toString() { }
    // public Iterator<T> preorder() { }
    // public Iterator<T> postorder() { }
}
```

`

```
BTNode class:
`
//*******************************************************************
// BTNode.java Java Foundations
//
// Represents a node in a binary tree with a left and right child.
// Therefore this class also represents the root of a subtree.
//*******************************************************************
package javafoundations;
public class BTNode<T>
{       
    protected T element;
    protected BTNode<T> left, right;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates a new tree node with the specified data.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public BTNode (T element)
    {
        this.element = element;
        left = right = null;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the element stored in this node.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public T getElement()
    {
        return element;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------- 
    // Sets the element stored in this node.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setElement (T element)
    {
        this.element = element;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the left subtree of this node.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public BTNode<T> getLeft()
    {
        return left;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sets the left child of this node.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setLeft (BTNode<T> left)
    {
        this.left = left;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the right subtree of this node.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public BTNode<T> getRight()
    {
        return right;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sets the right child of this node.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setRight (BTNode<T> right)
    {
        this.right = right;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the element in this subtree that matches the
    // specified target. Returns null if the target is not found.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public BTNode<T> find (T target)
    {
        BTNode<T> result = null;
        if (element.equals(target))
            result = this;
        else
        {
            if (left != null)
                result = left.find(target);
            if (result == null && right != null)
                result = right.find(target);
        }
        return result;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the number of nodes in this subtree.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public int count()
    {
        int result = 1;
        if (left != null)
            result += left.count();
        if (right != null)
            result += right.count();
        return result;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Performs an inorder traversal on this subtree, updating the
    // specified iterator.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public void inorder (ArrayIterator<T> iter)
    {
        if (left != null)
            left.inorder (iter);
        iter.add (element);
        if (right != null)
            right.inorder (iter);
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // The following methods are left as programming projects.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // public void preorder(ArrayIterator<T> iter) { }
    // public void postorder(ArrayIterator<T> iter) { }
}
```

`

Comment: Why down vote my question? 
This is an honest question. The programming project doesn't make sense as asked in the book in the same chapter the code is given in. Maybe it's something simple, Idk.

Comment: I understand trees (in a mathematical sense and a computer science sense (yes they are different)). I can read the code and know exactly what it is. I understand it's similar to linked lists in that each node has a reference to its data and a reference to its child nodes and in this case it also wants a reference to its parents node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion here means they want your binary tree implementation to be self-referencing. That means that instead of having a node reference its left and right node as the book example has, you would have the tree itself referencing left and right `BinaryTree` subtrees, and then a reference to its root element.

If you look at your instructions, notice it says that the tree itself has references to its left and right sub trees, as well as its element, while the book implementation relies on the `Node` class having the `getRight()` and `getLeft()` etc. methods.

Comment: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/binarytrees/
This one also relies on the Node class for getRight() and getLeft(). Hmm..